# Optimize this working jquery code ? (set automatic "tabindex" )

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

The idea is to set automatically a "tabindex" for every "select, input" and "a" element.
I found that peace of code, but it seems to slow down the page extremly :-

```
$(function(){
var tabindex = 1;
$('input,select').each(function() {
    if (this.type != "hidden") {
        var $input = $(this);
        $input.attr("tabindex", tabindex);
        tabindex++;
     }
  });
});
```

Is it a better approach to use C#, if so what would be the idea using "FormCollection"?

Thanks..

Comment: What is the point of this code? `$.each` will select the elements as they are ordered in the DOM, which is the tab order (unless you have already set tabindex), so all you are doing is explicitly setting the value of tabindex to the value it already implicitly has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while maybe not entirely necessary to run this code, but you could do:

```
$(function(){
    $.each($('input:visible,select:visible,a:visible'), function(i, el) {            
        $(el).attr("tabindex", i);
    });
});
```

Comment: Apologies, missed the jquery selector, updated the code and created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/H69ES/

Comment: Why does this not work : " if ($(el).type != "hidden")" ?(it would like to check wether there is some "hidden"type)

Comment: there won't be, as :visible selects only visible elements. you could use attr("type"),however, not all the elements in the select will have an attribute called type, so you would need to cater for that

Comment: ok,thanks. Does it make sense to define "tabindex" on a mobile device ?

Comment: Not for my money it doesn't, no.

Comment: What do you mean "Not for my money" ?

Comment: for my money - used before you say something to show that it is your opinion : http://www.idiomconnection.com/money.html